# Android Parcel and Pass an object with a Listener on it

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

Is there any way I can pass a Parcelable (via Intent) that has a View.OnClickListener on it?

Basically I want to be able to start a common Actvity from anywhere and pass over the OnClickListener for a button which is defined on the Activity.

Alternatively I don't need to send the OnClickListener, it can just be a custom interface implementation that a fixed OnClickListener can callback to, the problem is I can't see any way to parcel anything like a callback (a method that can later be called)

I had tried the following

```
  destParcel.writeValue(mListener)
```

but it threw the following

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
```

So is there anyway to write a parcellable callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I can pass a Parcelable (via Intent) that has a View.OnClickListener on it?

Not in any meaningful fashion. Parceling is copy-by-value, not copy-by-reference, so it is not the same object on the receiving side as on the sending side.

> Basically I want to be able to start a common Actvity from anywhere and pass over the OnClickListener for a button which is defined on the Activity.

Use an event bus (Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.).

Or, use a `PendingIntent`.

Or, use a `Messenger`.

Or, use a `ResultReceiver`, which is the closest thing there is to a "parcellable callback".

Comment: Thanks, in one case I want to call a method on a 3rd part class which I can't make parcellable, that's why I was thinking about trying to make the listener itself parcelable. I'll look at how I can achieve what I want with PendingIntent then and use Otto otherwise. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a class that extends View.OnClickListener and implement Parcelable interface. If you have multiple listeners they can implement a common interface with the method you want to call.

This will work as long as you can save and restore all class members in/to a Parcel. However, if your listener wants to reference View objects this will not work and wouldn't make much sense to send it.

Comment: No it needs to send intents and/or take other actions but not reference anything. However as far as I know I still can't write the Parcelable. How do I parcel a reference to another executable method?

Comment: The method should be defined in your new class. You send an instance of the class and than unparcel later. There's now additional work needed for methods, just the members must be properly saved/restored.

Comment: Thansks for trying to help